# How do I differentiate between GET & PUT request transaction in New relic, when URL is same?

Tags: java, tomcat, monitoring, newrelic

I am monitoring my web application(CXF, Spring, Hibernate) running on Tomcat 7, using New Relic Java agent 2.18.0.

My services has end point URLs such that they are same for GET & PUT request only HTTP method is different, but when I look at "web transactions" I see only 1 URL instead of separate URLs for separate methods because of which I cannot find whether GET request is slow or PUT request . Is there any config/hack using which I can divide transactions further by HTTP methods instead of just URL strings?

Comment: Would it matter? I seriously doubt any slowness is due to the HTTP method.

Comment: I mean to say average time for GET requests is different from average time for PUT because they execute different code internally, but since it is merging both type of transactions together, the average time is average of GET & PUT request times. Because of this it is difficult to understand which one pulling up average time

Comment: I don't really understand still. But there must be some servlet acting as a filter in the framework you are using. Did you consider extending it and writing something to log the different request types?

Comment: I use CXF and it does write different things for different method in logs, but here I am not talking about logs, I am talking about New Relic console where transactions are shown by url not URL+HTTP method and AFAIK New Relic should be able to do this without me changing my code.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood. I have no idea how to do that :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately your best bet is to make an API call to set the transaction name to what you want.

https://newrelic.com/docs/java/naming-web-transactions

If you think adding the method automatically is a valuable feature, I suggest submiting a feature request to New Relic support.

Comment: Attempt to get better "Web Transaction" metrics in NewRelic console, reference: https://newrelic.com/docs/java/naming-web-transactions

Comment: This is not limited to java btw.  I find it a pretty bad limitation of New Relic.  I have a similar problem.  My GET call is far less an issue then my PUT since my PUT is writing the DB and doing other calculations.  The GET is far simpler so generally takes a lot less time.  I used to use AppDynamics and there you can easily report separately on each method.  New Relic doesn't seem to have that unless you actually add it to your code and name the transaction differently.